# Creating an objective-c file creation event stream

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to create a stream to monitor a few directories for new files but I've had no luck.
Bonus points if your solution recursively searches the directories.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you having problems? We're not here to provide source code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read the "Tracking File-System Changes" section of the [File-System Performance Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/FileSystem/Articles/TrackingChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001993-CJBJFIDD) - this and the [NSWorkspace class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html) should tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: +1 aw, @middaparka I was just about to post the `NSWorkspace` class ref.  :(

Comment: @Stephen Furlani - Sorry, I'll delete my answer and you can add yours. ;-)